# R can I reshape and prefix with a value

Tags: r, reshape

If I have a table tall by form with 2 variables X1 X2, how can I get wide by form with the wide names a combination of form value and variable name

```
tall <- data.frame( form=letters[1:3], x1=11:13, x2=21:23 )
```

So I have:

```
  form x1 x2
1    a 11 21
2    b 12 22
3    c 13 23
```

and I want

```
a.x1 a.x2 b.x1 b.x2 c.x1 c.x2
11   21   12   22   13   23
```

this seems to have aspects of dcast to go wide, and aspects of tidy functions splicing variable names

Comment: thanks markus, sorry about typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution with `tidyr::pivot_wider`:

```
wide <- tall %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = form, values_from = c('x1', 'x2'), names_sep = '.')
```

```
   x1.a  x1.b  x1.c  x2.a  x2.b  x2.c
  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1    11    12    13    21    22    23
```

To address the column names, I came up with this (*not elegant, but works for this example*):

```
names(wide) <- paste0(str_extract(pattern = '[A-z]?$', string = names(wide)), '.', str_extract(pattern = '^[:alnum:]*', string = names(wide)))

# plus arranging columns:
wide <- wide %>%
  select(starts_with(c('a', 'b', 'c')))
```

```
# A tibble: 1 x 6
   a.x1  a.x2  b.x1  b.x2  c.x1  c.x2
  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1    11    21    12    22    13    23
```

Comment: I can live with the suffix instead of prefix. This seems right. I am going wider, so pivot_wider seem more appropriate than split and unlist.

Comment: For what it's worth, you can match your expected output if instead of `pivot_wider` you use `pivot_wider_spec` with a custom `spec`: `spec <- build_wider_spec(tall, names_from = form, values_from = 2:3) %>% mutate(.name = map_chr(str_split(.name, "_"), ~paste0(rev(.x), collapse = "."))); pivot_wider_spec(tall, spec)`

Comment: the ordering of the columns is also all the x1 then all the x2, and not all the a followed by all the b and c. I can correct this by reordering the columns.

Answer (score 2):

You can split the data frame by form, remove the first column, and unlist:

```
unlist(lapply(split(tall, tall$form), `[`, -1))

a.x1 a.x2 b.x1 b.x2 c.x1 c.x2 
  11   21   12   22   13   23
```

Although the above returns a named vector and assumes don't have multiple values by form. If this isn't the case and you want a data frame you can do:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

tall %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = form, values_from = c(x1, x2), values_fn = list(x1 = list, x2 = list)) %>%
  unnest(cols = everything()) %>%
  rename_all(~ gsub("^(.*)_(.*)$", "\\2.\\1", .x))
```

Comment: I like the use of unlist to get the prefix.vname

Answer (score 1):

One simple solution is to use `reshape`, i.e.,

```
r <- reshape(cbind(id = 1,tall),
             direction = "wide",
             idvar = "id",
             timevar = "form")[-1]
```

such that

```
> r
  x1.a x2.a x1.b x2.b x1.c x2.c
1   11   21   12   22   13   23
```

**EDIT**

If you do care about the column names, you can go through the code below:

- using `reshape`+`setNames`, i.e.,

```
r <- setNames(r <- reshape(cbind(id = 1,tall),
                           direction = "wide",
                           idvar = "id",
                           timevar = "form")[-1],
              gsub("(.*)\\.(.*)","\\2\\.\\1",names(r)))
```

such that

```
> r
  a.x1 a.x2 b.x1 b.x2 c.x1 c.x2
1   11   21   12   22   13   23
```

- Or using `outer`

```
r <- setNames(c(t(tall[-1])),
              c(t(outer(tall$form,names(tall[-1]),paste,sep = "."))))
```

such that

```
> r
 a.x1 a.x2 b.x1 b.x2 c.x1 c.x2
   11   21   12   22   13   23
```

Answer (score 1):

A `data.table` option using `dcast`

```
library(data.table)

dcast(setDT(tall), rowid(form)~form, value.var = c('x1', 'x2'), sep = '.')[,form := NULL][]

#   x1.a x1.b x1.c x2.a x2.b x2.c
#1:   11   12   13   21   22   23
```

Comment: this has the appeal of pivot_wider. it is similar to things I tried before posting. I did not have the rowid(form)~form - I'm still thinking about that part. It is nice to see it all done by reference, including :=NULL versus [,-1]. I can see the final [] forces display, but not sure why dropping form prevents display.

Comment: Usually when we want to reshape the data we need a unique key on which we pivot the data, hence I use `rowid` here to create a unique key. As it is not needed in the final output, I delete it with `form := NULL`.